# How to add styles(color, font-size etc.) Laravel-Excel v3

Tags: excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

The scenario is this. When you click the button, it will download the excel sheet. Downloading the file is not problem. Only the styling on the excel. I'm using the `maatwebsite/excel` v3 package. I've tried the code below, but it's not adding any styles(color, font-size etc.) on the excel.

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
            $event->sheet->autoSize();
            $event->sheet->getPageSetup()
                #->setOrientation(PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                ->setFitToPage(true)
                #->setFitToWidth(400)
                #->setHorizontalCentered(true)
                ->setVerticalCentered(true);
        },
        Style::class => function(Style $style) {
            $style->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(Color::COLOR_RED);
        }
    ];
}
```